# How can I mount a monitor to a wall without drilling into brick?

Tags: mounting, brick, television

I'm looking to mount a larger computer monitor in my wall, running a little app to help me track buses. However, most of the walls in my apartment are brick, so traditional mounting is not an option. I rent, so I can't drill into the brick itself, but we have permission to drill into the mortar for any mounting.

Am I screwed trying to hang up this monitor, or is there some sort of mount that could hold a +/- 10 pound monitor in the mortar of the wall?

Note: The monitor is VESA compatible, so something using that is totally on the table

Comment: Consider adding felt or silicone pads to the back of the mount at key locations. It'll protect the brick and eliminate crunchy sounds.

Comment: If your intention is for a mount that holds the screen beyond 6" from the face of the wall, then that's important additional information.

Answer (score 3):

Ten pounds isn't particularly heavy and almost *any* anchor suitable for installation into a mortar joint would probably be sufficient to hold 10 lbs. Installing 4 of them (as would be recommended for any wall mount) should give you *more* than enough holding power.

Probably the most difficult part would be finding one that matches up nicely with your mortar joint pattern. I'd suggest finding one with multiple mounting options, or, simply drill a new hole or two in the wall-mount plate to match up with where the mortar joints are.

Answer (score 3):

It's trivial to hold 10-20 lbs if you can put anchors into the mortar (bricks are not tiles, so mortar, not grout.)

Typically with most mounts you'll need a board (3/4"-19mm or so thick, perhaps) with mounting holes spaced for the mortar gaps on the one direction, and the mount plate holes in the other direction. Tee nuts for the mount screws installed from the back before mounting to the wall would be a good method to make sure those hold.

For a 10 lb monitor (VESA 75 or 100) in a fixed position you might well be able to find a mount with just a couple of screw holes you can mount directly to one mortar joint. *e.g.* this, seen from the wall side with both 75 and 100 VESA holes.

[image: VESA mount, fixed/basic]

*[Image source](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images500x500/tote_vision_wm_32_fixed_vesa_75x75mm_and_1386839.jpg), no endorsement*

Alternatively, park a bookshelf against the wall and put the monitor on it.